# Get commit date from gerrit url

Tags: git, date, gerrit, git-commit

I have the gerrit url and I want to get the commit date. Gerrit query does not give you the commit date. It gives only createOn and lastupdatedOn. If I add a comment on the gerrit change, the lastUpdatedOn value changes so I am reluctant to use it. Is there a way to get the commit-date since it is displayed on gerrit? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As every change can consist oft multiple commits, you have to specify, which revision to query using the [Revision Endpoint's Get Commit](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#get-commit) API:

```
 GET /changes/{change-id}/revisions/{revision-id}/commit
```

To further quote the documentation:

> Request

```
GET /changes/myProject~master~I8473b95934b5732ac55d26311a706c9c2bde9940/revisions/674ac754f91e64a0efb8087e59a176484bd534d1/commit HTTP/1.0
```

> As response a CommitInfo entity is returned that describes the revision.
>
> Response

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Disposition: attachment
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

  )]}'
  {
    "commit": "674ac754f91e64a0efb8087e59a176484bd534d1",
    "parents": [
      {
        "commit": "1eee2c9d8f352483781e772f35dc586a69ff5646",
        "subject": "Migrate contributor agreements to All-Projects."
      }
    ],
    "author": {
      "name": "Shawn O. Pearce",
      "email": "sop@google.com",
      "date": "2012-04-24 18:08:08.000000000",
      "tz": -420
    },
    "committer": {
      "name": "Shawn O. Pearce",
      "email": "sop@google.com",
      "date": "2012-04-24 18:08:08.000000000",
      "tz": -420
    },
    "subject": "Use an EventBus to manage star icons",
    "message": "Use an EventBus to manage star icons\n\nImage widgets that need to ..."
  }
```

> Adding query parameter links (for example /changes/…​/commit?links) returns a CommitInfo with the additional field web_links.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your reply! So first I need to do a gerrit-query parse the change-id and revision-id from the json and then make this request right?